# rewrite rule for any subdomain to main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site called mailcake.com, and I would like to have beta.mailcake.com, to redirect to mailcake.com, How can I achieve this? I have it like this on /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailcake.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mailcake
    ServerName mailcake.com
    ServerAlias www.mailcake.com beta.mailcake.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.mailcake\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://mailcake.com" [L,P]   

    ErrorLog /var/log/mailcake.com-error_log
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mailcake
    ServerName mailcake.com
    ServerAlias www.mailcake.com

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/mailcake.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/mailcake.key
    ErrorLog /var/log/mailcake.com-error_log
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but it does not work

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is installed and loaded? Have you tried rewriting anything else to check?

Comment: @ZeWaren yes it is installed and loaded, I tried to rewrite something else, and it work fine

Comment: You can try to setup a custom log to see the result of apache's rewritings and check what is wrong. See http://zewaren.net/site/?q=node/88

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work when tested with a few URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(beta\.)?mailcake\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://mailcake.com/$1 [QSA]
```

Part of the important bit here is adding the `$1` to ensure that any paths get added to the URL (in your example, `http://beta.mailcake.com/stats/` would get redirected to `http://mailcake.com/`, which possibly isn't desireable.  Also, adding `[QSA]` should ensure any query strings are passed along too.

If you're doing the redirect within the `httpd.conf`, I probably also wouldn't add `[L]`, as it could stop other valid redirects within any `.htaccess` files from working.